how to update chart tradingview
I am working on a trading view chart, and in the program I am writing, there is a section that should be taken from the API by selecting a drop-down and display it on the chart.
My problem is that I get the data from the API, but the chart is not updated with the new data. Please help me.
main.js:
// Datafeed implementation`
import Datafeed from './datafeed.js';

const hashtag = decodeURIComponent(window.location.pathname);
const result = hashtag.split('/');
console.log('result:', result);

var widget = new TradingView.widget({
symbol: ${result[3]},
interval: '1h',
timeframe: '1h',
timezone: 'Asia/Tehran',
fullscreen: true,
container: 'tv_chart_container',
debug: true,
enabled_features: ['request_only_visible_range_on_reset', side_toolbar_in_fullscreen_mode'],
disabled_features: ['header_screenshot'],
datafeed: Datafeed,
library_path: 'advanced-chart/charting_library_cloned_data/charting_library/',`
locale: 'fa',
theme: 'dark',
autosize: 'true',
custom_css_url: "css/style.css",
custom_font_family: "yekan",
custom_formatters: {
timeFormatter: {
format: (date) => {
const _format_str = '%h:%m';
return _format_str
.replace('%h', date.getUTCHours(), 2)
.replace('%m', date.getUTCMinutes(), 2)
.replace('%s', date.getUTCSeconds(), 2);
}
},
dateFormatter: {
format: (date) => {
return new Intl.DateTimeFormat("fa", { year: "numeric", month: "long", day: "2-digit", hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' }).format(date);
}
},
tickMarkFormatter: (date, tickMarkType) => {
let jalaliDate = toJalali(date);
console.log('tickMarkFormatter:', { date, jalaliDate, tickMarkType });
switch (tickMarkType) {
case 'Year':
return jalaliDate.jy;
case 'Month':
return jalaliDate.jm;
case 'DayOfMonth':
return jalaliDate.jd;
case 'Time':
return jalaliDate.jh;
case 'TimeWithSeconds':
return '';
}
throw new Error('Unhandled tick mark type ' + tickMarkType);
},
priceFormatterFactory: (symbolInfo, minTick) => {
if (symbolInfo?.fractional || minTick !== 'default' && minTick.split(',')[2] === 'true') {
return {
format: (price, signPositive) => {
// return the appropriate format
},
};
}
return null;
},
studyFormatterFactory: (format, symbolInfo) => {
if (format.type === 'price') {
const numberFormat = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { notation: scientific' });
return {
format: (value) => numberFormat.format(value)
};
`}
if (format.type === 'volume') {
return {
format: (value) => (value / 1e9).toPrecision(format?.precision || 2) + 'B'
};`
}
if (format.type === 'percent') {
return {
format: (value) => ${value.toPrecision(format?.precision || 4)} percent
};
}
return null;
},
}
});

widget.headerReady().then(function () {
// Create a custom button
const button = widget.createButton({
align: 'left'
});

    button.setAttribute('title', 'twite');
    button.className = 'custom-button';
    
    button.innerHTML = 'send analyze'

    button.addEventListener('click', async function () {
        try {
            if ($userLoggedIn === 0) {
                window.location.href = '/authentication';
                return;
            }
    
            $('#screenShotChart').modal('show');
            $('#screenShotChart').on('shown.bs.modal', async function () {
                const screenshotCanvas = await widget.takeClientScreenshot();
                // Convert the screenshot to a Base64 string
                const base64String = screenshotCanvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                // Log the Base64 string to the console
                console.log(base64String);
                $('#screenshotChartBase64').val(base64String);
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error taking screenshot:', error);
        }
    });
    
    button.style.marginLeft = '10px';

});

widget.headerReady().then(function () {
widget.createDropdown({
title: 'تعدیل نمودار',
items: [
{
title: 'تعدیل شده',
onSelect: async () => {
const chart = widget.activeChart();
const symbolInfo = widget.activeChart().symbol(); // تغییر به symbolExt
const resolution = widget.activeChart().resolution();
const now = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000); // زمان فعلی به ثانیه
const from = now - 365 * 24 * 60 * 60; // یک سال پیش

     if (!symbolInfo || !resolution) {                     console.error('Invalid symbolInfo or resolution');                     return;                 }                   const onHistoryCallback = (bars) => {                     let series = chart.getSeries();                     if (series.length > 0) {                         // بروزرسانی داده‌های سری موجود                         series[0].setData(bars);                     } else {                         // ایجاد سری جدید و اضافه کردن داده‌ها                         const newSeries = chart.addSeries({                             type: 'candlestick',                             title: symbolInfo.name,                         });                         newSeries.setData(bars);                     }                 };                  const onErrorCallback = (error) => {                     console.error('Error fetching bars:', error);                 };                  await Datafeed.getBars(symbolInfo, resolution, from, onHistoryCallback, onErrorCallback, 1);             },         },`         {             title: 'تعدیل نشده',             onSelect: async () => {                 console.log(widget);                 const symbolInfo = widget.activeChart().symbol(); // تغییر به symbolExt                 const resolution = widget.activeChart().resolution();                 const now = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000); // زمان فعلی به ثانیه                 const from = now - 365 * 24 * 60 * 60; // یک سال پیش                  const chart = widget.activeChart();                 const series = chart.getSeries();                 console.log(series);                 console.log(chart);                  if (!symbolInfo || !resolution) {                     console.error('Invalid symbolInfo or resolution');                     return;                 }                  const onHistoryCallback =  (bars,meta)=>{                  } ; 


const onErrorCallback = (error) => {
console.error('Error fetching bars:', error);
};

                    await handleDropdownSelect(symbolInfo, resolution, from, onHistoryCallback, onErrorCallback, null);
    
    
                },
            },
        ],
    }).then(myDropdownApi => {
        // Dropdown API می‌توانید از myDropdownApi استفاده کنید
    });

});
function toJalali(date) {
let jalaliDateFormat = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("fa", { year: "numeric", month: "long", day: "2-digit", hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', second: 2-digit' });
let parts = jalaliDateFormat.formatToParts(date);
if (parts.length >= 11) {
return {
jy: parts[4].value,
jm: parts[2].value,
jd: parts[0].value,
jh: parts[6].value + parts[7].value + parts[8].value,
};
}
throw new Error('Invalid parts array length');
}

datafeed.js
import {
makeApiRequest,
generateSymbol,
parseFullSymbol,
} from './helpers.js';
import {widget} from "../charting_library_cloned_data/charting_library";

const lastBarsCache = new Map();

const configurationData = {
supported_resolutions: ['1h','4h','24h','1D','1w'],
exchanges: [
{
value: 'همه بازار ها',
name: 'عمومی',
desc: '',
},
{
value: 'بورس',
name: 'بورس',
desc: ''
},
],
symbols_types: [{
name: 'همه',
value: '0',
},
{
name: 'سهام',
value: '1',
}],
};

async function getAllSymbols() {
const data = await makeApiRequest('api/symbol/all');

    let allSymbols = [];
    for (const exchange of configurationData.exchanges) {
        for (const leftPairPart of data) {
            allSymbols.push({
                symbol: leftPairPart.LVal18AFC,
                full_name: leftPairPart.LVal18AFC,
                description: leftPairPart.LSoc30,
                exchange: exchange.value,
                type: 'بورس',
            });
        }
    }
    return allSymbols;

}

export default {
onReady: (callback) => {
console.log('[onReady]: Method call');
setTimeout(() => callback(configurationData));
},

    searchSymbols: async (
        userInput,
        exchange,
        symbolType,
        onResultReadyCallback,
    ) => {
        console.log('[searchSymbols]: Method call');
        const symbols = await getAllSymbols();
        const newSymbols = symbols.filter(symbol => {
            const isExchangeValid = exchange === 'همه بازار ها' || symbol.exchange === exchange;
            const isFullSymbolContainsInput = symbol.full_name && symbol.full_name.indexOf(userInput) !== -1;
            return isExchangeValid && isFullSymbolContainsInput;
        });
        onResultReadyCallback(newSymbols);
    },
    resolveSymbol: async (
        symbolName,
        onSymbolResolvedCallback,
        onResolveErrorCallback,
        extension
    ) => {
        console.log('[resolveSymbol]: Method call', symbolName);
        const symbols = await getAllSymbols();
        const symbolItem = symbols.find(({ full_name }) => full_name === symbolName);
        if (!symbolItem) {
            console.log('[resolveSymbol]: Cannot resolve symbol', symbolName);
            onResolveErrorCallback('cannot resolve symbol');
            return;
        }
        const symbolInfo = {
            ticker: symbolItem.full_name,
            name: symbolItem.symbol,
            description: symbolItem.description,
            type: symbolItem.type,
            session: '24x7',
            timezone: 'Asia/Tehran',
            exchange: symbolItem.exchange,
            minmov: 1,
            pricescale: 100,
            has_intraday: true,
            has_daily: true,
            intraday_multipliers: ['60','240','1440'],
            has_weekly_and_monthly: false,
            supported_resolutions: configurationData.supported_resolutions,
            volume_precision: 2,
            data_status: 'streaming',
        };
        console.log('[resolveSymbol]: Symbol resolved', symbolName);
        onSymbolResolvedCallback(symbolInfo);
    },
    getBars: async (symbolInfo, resolution, from, onHistoryCallback,onErrorCallback, isTadil = null) => {
        if (!symbolInfo || !resolution) {
            console.error('[getBars]: Invalid symbolInfo or resolution');
            onErrorCallback('Invalid symbolInfo or resolution');
            return;
        }
    
        try {
    
    
            const hashtag = decodeURIComponent(window.location.pathname);
            const result = hashtag.split('/');
            console.log(symbolInfo.name)
          if(symbolInfo.name!==result[3]  && symbolInfo.name!=undefined)
          {
              window.location.href=`http://127.0.0.1:8000/twitter/hashtag/${symbolInfo.name}`
          }
    
    
            const apiUrl = isTadil !== null ? `/api/symbol/${symbolInfo}/tadil` : `/api/symbol/${symbolInfo.name}`;
            const res = await fetch(apiUrl);
    
            console.log(isTadil,apiUrl);
    
            if (!res.ok) {
                throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
            }
    
            const data = await res.json();
    
            if (!Array.isArray(data)) {
                throw new Error('Data format is incorrect');
            }
    
            console.log('Received data:', data);
    
            let bars = data.map(bar => {
                let timestamp = bar.jdates && bar.jdates.$date && bar.jdates.$date.$numberLong
                    ? parseInt(bar.jdates.$date.$numberLong) : null;
    
                if (!isNaN(timestamp)) {
                    return {
                        time: timestamp,
                        open: parseFloat(bar.open),
                        high: parseFloat(bar.high),
                        low: parseFloat(bar.low),
                        close: parseFloat(bar.close),
                        volume: parseFloat(bar.volume, 10),
                        isBarClosed: true,
                        isLastBar: false,
                    };
                } else {
                    console.log(`Invalid date for bar: ${JSON.stringify(bar)}`);
                    return null;
                }
            });
    
            const filteredBars = bars.filter(bar => bar && bar.time !== null && bar.time !== undefined );
    
            if (resolution === '1D') {
                if (filteredBars.length > 0) {
                    bars = convertIntradayToDaily(filteredBars, lastBarsCache.get(symbolInfo.name) || []);
                } else {
                    bars = [];
                }
            } else {
                bars = filteredBars;
            }
    
            const uniqueBars = Array.from(new Set(bars.map(bar => bar.time)))
                .map(time => {
                    return bars.find(bar => bar.time === time);
                });
    
            uniqueBars.sort((a, b) => a.time - b.time);
    
            const finalBars = [];
            let lastTime = null;
    
            for (const bar of uniqueBars) {
                if (lastTime === null || bar.time > lastTime) {
                    finalBars.push(bar);
                    lastTime = bar.time;
                } else {
                    console.log(`Skipped duplicate or out-of-order bar: ${bar.time}`);
                }
            }
    
            console.log('Filtered and Sorted Bars:', finalBars);
            console.log(`[getBars]: returned ${finalBars.length} bar(s)`);
    
            onHistoryCallback(finalBars, {
                noData: finalBars.length === 0,
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('[getBars]: Get error', error);
            onErrorCallback(error);
        }
    
    
    
    },
    subscribeBars: (symbolInfo, resolution, onRealtimeCallback, subscriberUID, onResetCacheNeededCallback) => {
        console.log('[subscribeBars]: Method call with:', { symbolInfo, resolution, subscriberUID });
    
        // Add your subscription logic here
        // Store the subscription data in the lastBarsCache or any other state management
    },
    
    unsubscribeBars: (subscriberUID) => {
        console.log('[unsubscribeBars]: Method call with:', { subscriberUID });
    
        // Add your unsubscription logic here
        // Remove the subscription data from the lastBarsCache or any other state management
    },

};

function convertIntradayToDaily(intradayData, cachedData) {
const getTimeRange = (data) => {
if (data.length === 0) return { start: null, end: null };
const start = new Date(data[0].time);
const end = new Date(data[data.length - 1].time);
return { start, end };
}

    const newTimeRange = getTimeRange(intradayData);
    const cachedTimeRange = getTimeRange(cachedData);
    
    if (newTimeRange.start && cachedTimeRange.start &&
        newTimeRange.start.getTime() === cachedTimeRange.start.getTime() &&
        newTimeRange.end.getTime() === cachedTimeRange.end.getTime()) {
        console.log('Time range of received data is the same as cached one. Skip the update.');
        return cachedData;
    }
    
    const dailyData = [];
    let dailyCandle = null;
    let currentDay = null;
    
    intradayData.forEach(candle => {
        const date = new Date(candle.time);
        const day = date.toISOString().split('T')[0];
    
        if (currentDay !== day) {
            if (dailyCandle) {
                dailyData.push(dailyCandle);
            }
            currentDay = day;
            dailyCandle = {
                time: date.getTime(),
                open: candle.open,
                high: candle.high,
                low: candle.low,
                close: candle.close,
                volume: candle.volume
            };
        } else {
            dailyCandle.high = Math.max(dailyCandle.high, candle.high);
            dailyCandle.low = Math.min(dailyCandle.low, candle.low);
            dailyCandle.close = candle.close;
            dailyCandle.volume += candle.volume;
        }
    });
    
    if (dailyCandle) {
        dailyData.push(dailyCandle);
    }
    
    return dailyData;

}

I expected the chart to update but it didn't
